# Wrong output ASCII to closest prime number

Tags: c, arrays, string

Q.> A string(capital letters) is given as Input. Consider ASCII value of every characters of the string and replace it with the closest prime number and print that string.

ex: `ABCDEF`, corresponding ascii are: *65,66,67,68,69,70*

After replacing every value with closest prime *67,67,67,67,67,71* it gives `CCCCCG` as output
[note: if two primes are equidistant consider lower(69 is closest to both 67 and 71 but consider 67).]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int closestprime(int x)
{
  int primes[6]={67,71,73,79,83,89},i;
  for(i=0;i<6;i++)
  {
    if(x<primes[i])
    {
      if(x<=69)
          return 67;
      else{
        if((x-primes[i-1])>(primes[i]-x))
          return primes[i];
        else
          return primes[i-1];
      }

      if (x==90||x==91)
        return 89;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  int i,j,cases,length;
  scanf("%d%d",&cases,&length);
  char *str;
  str=(char *)malloc((length+1)*sizeof(char));
  for(j=0;j<cases;j++){

    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",str+i);
    }

    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        str[i]=(char) closestprime((int) str[i]);
        printf("%c",str[i]);
    }

    free(str);
    printf("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here my code generating an unwanted  single 'C' character every time AT THE BEGINNING. Output should be  `SCSSCC` it is generating `CSCSSC`. It is also missing the last `C`.

```
> 1
> 6
> TESTED
> CSCSSC
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of the input file?

Comment: Your allocation of the `str` variable is problematic. You allocate it only once, but you free it for each case. This leads me to believing that you're actually misreading the input.

Comment: 1st line : no of testcases(n) then length of the string and input string for n times

Comment: Please don't post a graphic that contains text. Use the context menu Edit->Mark and select with the mouse. Then you have text in the clipboard that can be easily pasted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After typing the input string "TESTED" your program is taking 'Enter'  as an `\n` input into the input buffer. Your `scanf("%c",str+i);` is reading '\n' as an input.

You need to clear your input buffer.

use `fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);` after `scanf("%d%d",&cases,&length);`

```
    int i,j,cases,length;
    scanf("%d%d",&cases,&length);
    fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
    //.....
```

or you can also put a white space in your `scanf(" %c",str+i);`